# Image not displaying on browser using servlet

Tags: java

I'm using SQLServerr 2012 Management Studio. I want to retrieve image from the database and display it in the browser. I have taken data type for the image is image datatype as it has not option to take blob data type.

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
{

    //PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
          String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost; databaseName=JDBC1; user=sa; password=123;"; 
            java.sql.Connection con=null;
            try{            
                 Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");     
                 con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl); 
                Statement st1=con.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs1 = st1.executeQuery("select image from image_table");
                String imgLen="";
                if(rs1.next()){
                    imgLen = rs1.getString(1);
                    System.out.println(imgLen.length());
                }   
                rs1 = st1.executeQuery("select image from image_table");
                if(rs1.next()){
                    int len = imgLen.length();
                    byte [] rb = new byte[len];
                    InputStream readImg = rs1.getBinaryStream(1);
                    int index=readImg.read(rb, 0, len); 
                    System.out.println("index"+index);
                    st1.close();
                    response.reset();
                    response.setContentType("image/jpg");
                    response.getOutputStream().write(rb,0,len);
                    response.getOutputStream().flush();             
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }

}
```

Comment: What is happening that differs from what you expect/want? Please include a question in your question.

Comment: you are reading both image length and image with same sql `select image from image_table`