# How to display image in jsp file from database

Tags: jsp

How to display image in **jsp** file from database?

JSP code below:-

```
<%
  ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select img,name from books");
%>
<html>
<head>
 <title>ONLINE BOOK STORE - LOGIN PAGE</title>
</head>
<body>
 <table align=center>
  <tr>
   <td align=center><img src="logo.jpg"></img>
  <tr>
```

Where do we store the image to be extracted from database?

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

I did that in the past by writing a servlet which reads an image file from local file to alter the size and format on the fly. As an alternative the bytes of the images could be from a blob column of a database, it is similar. Then the servlet path could be addressed inside a JSP inside an image tag. Is this enough? Or do you need an sample code?

Comment: As an alternative to the servlet solution you could use inline images: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8499633/9267891

Comment: Need the sample code. Can you please send me?

Comment: Ok, but you understand that I will not do your (home) work here, instead I can point you to some directions.. By the way, before asking questions maybe you search stackoverflow a bit more (sample code): https://stackoverflow.com/q/50139756/9267891

Comment: Practical advice: Don't put large objects like images inside a database... Rather store the image file name inside the database and have the image in a specific directory on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Save image as `base64` string in db and render the string in `<img src="<%= rs.getString(0); %>">`

For converting image to `base64` string. move over here [Convert image to Base64 String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36492084/how-to-convert-an-image-to-base64-string-in-java)